# How can I increase back the "Forward" animation state float value back to 1 slowly if the player is facing the other direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the player animator controller not my controller there is a parameter name Forward.
When I press the W key to move the player forward it's increasing the value of the "Forward" from 0 to 1 min 0 max 1. From idle state forward is 0 to walk state forward is 1.

In the script attached to the player I did that when the player is reaching some distance the player is slowly smooth change from walk to idle until stop.

The problem is that now the "Forward" value is all the time 0. And I want to allow the player to move back and walk only if he move forward and reach the distance then slowly stop but if I press on S backward movement then increase back the value to 1 slowly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject distanceTarget;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    private Animator anim;

    float timeElapsed;
    float lerpDuration = 3;

    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, distanceTarget.transform.position);

        if (distance >= 61f)
        {
            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            text.text = "I can't move that far by foot. I need to find some transportation to move any further.";
        }
        else
        {
            text.text = "";
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This part make the player stop slowly smooth from walking to idle :

```
if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
```

This is a screenshot showing the player has reached the distanced and stopped. I moved the camera a bit to the side :

[image: Player]

Now I'm pressing the key A or since I changed the camera view with the mouse so I'm pressing on S but it doesn't matter the point is when I turn the player facing the other direction then facing the distance 61 the player should start slowly walking again by increasing the "Forward" value to 1.

But how do I know where the player is facing I mean if he is still facing the distance of 61 or if he is now facing the other direction ?

[image: Player is facing the other direction not the distance 61 the opposite direction but I can't make him walk since I don't know in the script how to tell that the player is facing now the opposite direction.]

What I tried now is in the else part using a new helper variable name newDir to check what direction the player is facing then to increase the "Forward" value but it does nothing :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject distanceTarget;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    private Animator anim;

    float timeElapsed;
    float lerpDuration = 3;

    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp;

    private Vector3 currentDir;
    private Vector3 newDir;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, distanceTarget.transform.position);

        if (distance >= 61f)
        {
            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            currentDir = transform.forward;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            text.text = "I can't move that far by foot. I need to find some transportation to move any further.";
        }
        else
        {
            if(newDir != currentDir)
            {
                startValue = 0;
                endValue = 1;
                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            }
            text.text = "";
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not clean and the best way but this is working just like I wanted.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject distanceTarget;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    private Animator anim;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 3;
    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp = 0;

    // Opposite Direction
    float timeElapsedOpposite = 0;
    float lerpDurationOpposite = 3;
    float startValueForOpposite = 0;
    float endValueForOpposite = 1;
    float valueToLerpOpposite = 0;   

    float angle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, distanceTarget.transform.position);
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        if (distance >= 61f && angle < 180)
        {
            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsedOpposite = 0;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            text.text = "I can't move that far by foot. I need to find some transportation to move any further.";
        }
        else
        {
            text.text = "";
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Get the angle:
        

        if (angle > 180f && distance >= 61f)
        {
            if (timeElapsedOpposite < lerpDurationOpposite)
            {
                valueToLerpOpposite = Mathf.Lerp(startValueForOpposite, endValueForOpposite, timeElapsedOpposite / lerpDurationOpposite);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerpOpposite);
                timeElapsedOpposite += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerpOpposite);

            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```